# Error with openpyxl after converting a script to Python 3.x that utilizes pandas and numpy

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

About a year ago I wrote a script that took a single column of datetime values and ran a window through the series to determine the greatest "lumping" of values based on an adjustable dimension of time. For example, given a million date time values what is the maximum value of entries that exist within 1 second, or 1 minute, or 1 hour of each other.

The problem is that I had a machine blow up on me and lost some of the documentation, specifically the versions of packages that I was working with. I think I've updated the code to execute within 3.x but am now getting errors that seem to suggest that pandas no longer supports the packages I'm trying to use. I've tried just installing a few random versions, updating pip, etc., but am not having much luck.

The exact error states, 'UserWarning: Installed openpyxl is not supported at this time. Use >=1.61 and <2.0.0' -- I'm not seeing a version history in their repository. Might just try installing older versions of Python and trying to bash this into place.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Your original code was correct here. I assumed there will be a data column along with the timestamps.
df = pd.read_csv("ET.txt", parse_dates=["dt"])

# Construct a univariate `timeseries` instead of a single column dataframe as output by `read_csv`.
# You can think of a dataframe as a matrix with labelled columns and rows. A timeseries is more like
# an associative array, or labelled vector. Since we don't need a labelled column, we can use a simpler
# representation.
data = pd.Series(0, df.dt)  
print(data)
window_size = 1
buckets_sec = data.resample("1S", how="count").fillna(0)

# We have to shift the data back by the same number of samples as the window size. This is because `rolling_apply`
# uses the timestamp of the end of the period instead of the beginning. I assume you want to know when the most
# active period started, not when it ended. Finally, `dropna` will remove any NaN entries appearing in the warmup
# period of the sliding window (ie. it will output NaN for the first window_size-1 observations).
rolling_count = pd.rolling_apply(buckets_sec, window=window_size, func=np.nansum).shift(-window_size).dropna()
print(rolling_count.describe())

# Some interesting data massaging
# E.g. See how the maximum hit count over the specified sliding window evolves on an hourly
# basis:
seconds_max_hits = rolling_count.resample("S", how="max").dropna()

# Plot the frequency of various hit counts. This gives you an idea how frequently various
# hit counts occur.
seconds_max_hits.hist()

# Same on a daily basis
daily_max_hits = rolling_count.resample("S", how="max").dropna()
```

Screen cap of the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6T4Q.png

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're seeing an openpyxl related error but if you are it seems like you should update your version of Pandas. There were some significant changes in openpyxl that affected exporting to Excel from Pandas but these have since been resolved.